# How do I address a button? (OpenOffice Spreadsheet Macros)

Tags: macros, openoffice.org

I have a button which launches a macro in OpenOffice. Within the macro,  I want to change the name of the button. The original code for Excel is

```
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("PunchButton").select
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Punch In"
```

but the first line does nothing. I've checked the sheet in OpenOffice and the button has the right name. How do I get to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a snippet of code [here](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=74242) that shows how to change the label and state of all buttons but the one you desire.

```
Sub clickCommandButton1
    oPage = Thiscomponent.Sheets.getByName("Sheet1").getDrawPage
    iCount = oPage.getCount
    For i = 0 to iCount - 1
        oEle = oPage.getByIndex(i)
        oControl = oEle.getControl()
        If oControl.DefaultControl = "com.sun.star.form.control.CommandButton" Then
            ' Found command button - change label of other buttons '
            If oEle.Name <> "CommandButton1" Then
                oControl.Label = "Inactive"
                oControl.Enabled = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I would modify this to iterate over all the buttons but change the internal if-statement to '=" instead of "<>" (and remove the disabling if that's not needed).

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I'll check it out and post my code when it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pax, here's my working code. Not sure how robust it is, but for the sheet in question it works. Thanks again, Pax.

```
sub testThis
    setButtonLabel("PunchButton", "hello")
    setButtonLabel("ReportButton", "hello")
end sub

sub setButtonLabel(controlName, label)
    oPage = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet.getDrawPage
    iCount = oPage.getCount
    For i = 0 to iCount - 1
        oControl = oPage.getByIndex(i).getControl
        If oControl.Name = controlName Then
            oControl.label = label
            exit sub
        End If
    Next
end sub
```